# SSAS MOLAP Aggregations not working

Tags: ssas

When we run the aggregation wizard from Visual Studio for a MOLAP cube, no aggregations are created.  The graph stays flat.  We tried every different scenario and setting that we could think of with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

1. Do you have natural hierarchies in your dimensions? (Needed for optimal aggregation)
2. Do you have the correct attribute relations for those hierarchies? (Also, needed for optimal aggregation and performance)
3. Do you have non parent-child dimensions available to aggregate? (Only the key attribute will aggregate in these)
4. Do you have any data in your cube? (the wizard needs data to work)
5. Do you have partitions? (aggregations can't be created for higher levels than the partition split e.g. you can't have a year aggregation on a monthly partition)
6. Ensure that at least some dimension attributes have their AttributeHierarchyOptimizedState set to FullyOptimized
7. Check the AggregationUsage cube dimension attribute property

Also read:

- [What are the natural hierarchies and why they are a good thing](http://sqljunkies.com/WebLog/mosha/archive/2006/11/09/natural_hierarchy.aspx)
- [Influencing Aggregation Candidates](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/LIZ/post/Influencing-Aggregation-Candidates.aspx) (This has much more detail than here)